# List exceeds width of parent container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, html-lists

I want to build a navigation in the header containing three items where the first two ones are aligned left and the third one is aligned right. Tried it by use of flexbox but there is an arror: The ul is exceeding the width of it's parent container.

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  background: #417690;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 70px;
}

header ul {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  /* justify-content: center; */
}

header ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.filler {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Logo</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">New article</a></li>
    <li class="filler"></li>
    <li><a href="#">username</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

How can I fix this?
Tested in FF and Opera.

Comment: The filler item is completely unnecessary. Use a flex `auto` margin. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B Didn't like the filler and it's great that you provided a solution for doing without!

Answer (score 2):

Reset `margin` to zero and add `box-sizing: border-box` to all elements to include the `padding` in the size calculations. You may also reset the `padding` for the `ul` element - see demo below:

```css
* { /* ADDED */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  background: #417690;
  /*margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;*/
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 70px;
}

header ul {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  /* justify-content: center; */
  padding: 0; /* ADDED */
}

header ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.filler {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Logo</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">New article</a></li>
    <li class="filler"></li>
    <li><a href="#">username</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixes it indeed. What is the explanation? Does setting width  to 100% result in a width of (100% + padding + margin + border)?

Comment: @Sempervivum In the absence of any `box-sizing` property, yes.

Comment: @Sempervivum you should check this answer as the right one

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
header ul {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it.